# Genome-guided transcriptome reconstruction: should I filter my reference annotation by transcript_support_level or other tags?

Tags: rna-seq, stringtie, gencode

Is there really any advantage to filtering the GTF annotation for transcriptome reconstruction (or, for example, for pseudo-alignment quantification)? Are there any downsides (i.e. reasons why I should NOT do that)?

I'm going to run a transcriptome reconstruction with StringTie on several RNA-seq samples, and I want to be stringent in the detection of novel isoforms.

To do that, I'm thinking of filtering the reference annotation that I provide to StringTie, removing transcripts that are not well supported by strong evidences. I found that the GENCODE tag "transcript_support_level" could be what I should filter for.

However, I couldn't find anybody suggesting to filter the GENCODE reference annotation by the [transcript_support_level tag](https://www.gencodegenes.org/pages/data_format.html).

From the GENCODE documentation:

```
transcript_support_level    {1,2,3,4,5,NA} [0,1]
transcripts are scored according to how well mRNA and EST alignments match over its full length:
1 (all splice junctions of the transcript are supported by at least one non-suspect mRNA),
2 (the best supporting mRNA is flagged as suspect or the support is from multiple ESTs),
3 (the only support is from a single EST),
4 (the best supporting EST is flagged as suspect),
5 (no single transcript supports the model structure),
NA (the transcript was not analyzed)
```

I ran a test on GENCODE v40, and it seems that the cumulative distribution of genes from support level 1 to NA is:

```
SupportLevel | # genes
           1 | 19311
           2 | 23680
           3 | 28212
           4 | 29429
           5 | 31566
          NA | 61552
```

So it seems that I would miss out many genes from the reference annotation if I filter by, let's say, `transcript_support_level <= 2`

Couldn't find any info about advantages or disadvantages... apparently most people simply use the comprehensive GENCODE annotation with StringTie or Salmon or other tools like that, but I also know that these approaches generates many false detections that needs to be filtered downstream.

Hopefully I'm not the first person (over)thinking this :)